# Join Temp table and actual table with same columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table generated using PIVOT(So this will be having dynamic number of columns).And I have a sql table called dbo.User

My temp table is generated from audit table. which will be having same column names as dbo.User table. SO now I have to select if same column exists in both tables when i join I have to select values from temp instead of User table. I dont think it is a simple alias method joining. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance..

Code:

@cols give me the column names from audit table(Which are related to user table)I dont know the number of columns in this, dynamic number of columns

```
set @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT *, ' + @cols + ' 
                  FROM 
                 (
                    select
                      e.USER_KEY,
                      e.FIELD_NAME+''_AUDIT'' AS FIELD_NAME_AUDIT,
                      e.PREVIOUS_DATA as DATA
                      FROM temp e
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    max(DATA)
                    for FIELD_NAME_AUDIT in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p
                INNER JOIN USER xyz ON xyz.USER_KEY = p.USER_KEY'

         EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

I have appended '_AUDIT' to column name as to separate from actual table column name, because when i use inner join there is some ambiguity error.

Comment: Do you have a sample query that you have already tried and that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if any body understood my question, but here is my solution:
I have used another temp table to get all the columns from tbl_user and drop the columns using 
@cols and them inner join both temp tables:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM USER where USER_KEY= @User_key

set @query = '
                  ALTER TABLE #TempTable DROP COLUMN ' + @cols + '
                  SELECT DISTINCT p.*, xyz.* 
                  FROM 
                 (
                    select
                      e.USER_KEY,
                      e.FIELD_NAME,
                      e.PREVIOUS_DATA as DATA
                      FROM temp e
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    max(DATA)
                    for FIELD_NAME_AUDIT in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p
                INNER JOIN USER xyz ON xyz.USER_KEY = p.USER_KEY'

         EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```